# MSTest Code Coverage with DataRows Not Working

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, mstest, datarow

I have a simple convert method from one enum to another.

```
public static ServiceStatus FromTheirState(TheirState fromState)
{
    MyStatus newStatus;

    switch (fromState)
    {
        case TheirState.Online:
            newStatus = MyStatus.Online;
            break;

        case TheirState.Intermittent:
            newStatus = MyStatus.Intermittent;
            break;

        case TheirState.Offline:
        default:
            newStatus = MyStatus.Offline;
            break;

    }

    return newStatus;
}
```

To unit test this, I am doing the following

```
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(TheirState.Online, MyStatus.Online)]
    [DataRow(TheirState.Offline, MyStatus.Offline)]
    [DataRow(TheirState.Intermittent, MyStatus.Intermittent)]
    public void TestFromTheirState(TheirState state, MyStatus expectedStatus)
    {
        MyStatus actualStatus = StatusConverter.FromTheirState(state);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedStatus, actualStatus);
    }
```

Although the Test Results show that all 3 tests completed successfully (see below), the code coverage says the "Online" case is the only one covered.  The other two conversion cases are hightlighted not coverd. Any ideas?  Is this a bug?

```
Hierarchy                   Not Covered (Blocks)    Covered (% Blocks) Not Covered (% Blocks)   Covered (Blocks)    
FromTheirState(TheirState)      2                       66.67 %            33.33 %                  4
```

Test Results:

Test Name:  TestFromTheirState
Test FullName:  Manager.TestServiceStatus.TestFromTheirState
Test Outcome:   Passed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0072567

Result1 Name:   TestFromTheirState(Intermittent,Intermittent)
Result1 Outcome:    Passed
Result1 Duration:   0:00:00.0000028
Result1 StackTrace:
Result1 Message:
Result1 StandardOutput:
Result1 StandardError:

Result2 Name:   TestFromTheirState(Offline,Offline)
Result2 Outcome:    Passed
Result2 Duration:   0:00:00.0000278
Result2 StackTrace:
Result2 Message:
Result2 StandardOutput:
Result2 StandardError:

Result3 Name:   TestFromTheirState(Online,Online)
Result3 Outcome:    Passed
Result3 Duration:   0:00:00.0072261
Result3 StackTrace:
Result3 Message:
Result3 StandardOutput:
Result3 StandardError:

Comment: Can you provide some code of the convert method and which lines are shown as covered / not covered?

Comment: I edited the original question above with the details.  Thanks for your interest.